# (Android) Starting up a fragment is blocking LocationListener

Tags: java, android, facebook

So when I comment out past the facebook code comment, the Location manager does work and onLocationChanged does update the proper Latitude and Longitude. However, when I uncomment it, the Facebook functionality works but the onLocationChanged never gets called for some reason.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private MainFragment mainFragment;
    Button sendIPbutton; //Button for sending IP Address
    EditText mEdit; //Get info from what user enters in form
    //TextView mText;
    TextView coordinates;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/*/
        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);





/**************************Facebook code********************************************/

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
                    .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
/*********************************************************************************/
    }



    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            String Text = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude:  " + loc.getLongitude();
//            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            coordinates = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinates);

            coordinates.setText(Text);
        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                    "Gps Disabled",

                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }


        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }

    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.
                INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }

    public void setObject(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetObjectActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I think there must be something going on in the oncreate function.

Here is my MainFragment.java code. Note that it's primarily from the Facebook Login and Sharing tutorial on their website.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private Button shareButton;
    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
    private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private TextView coordinates;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private final List<String> permissions;

    public MainFragment() {
        permissions = Arrays.asList("user_status");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        shareButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        coordinates = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.coordinates);

        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                publishStory();
            }
        });
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization =
                    savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
        }
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
                (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (pendingPublishReauthorization &&
                    state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publishStory();
            }

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                         Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void publishStory() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }



            String text = coordinates.getText().toString();
            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "My Location!");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Thanks to Hot and Cold");
            postParams.putString("description", text);
            postParams.putString("link", null);
            postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                            .getGraphObject()
                            .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG,
                                "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getErrorMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                                        .getApplicationContext(),
                                postId,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
                    HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I was spot on about the Fragment causing the issue. to Resolve it, I just added Context to the fragment class, i imported all of the Location logic into MainFragment, and now it works!

Comment: can you please give more details on how you fixed this? got the same problem, but can't understand from your answer what you've done.